# HTML rich email invitation with RSVP button to database?

Tags: list, html-email, invite

What I am trying to do is this: 
Send an invitation for an event via HTML eblast. I would like the users to be able to RSVP straight from the email (click Yes, No, Maybe) and by doing so, will send that info into a database for my client to view the responses.

They specifically do not want responses coming in as emails, they want to view it as a list, and does not want to use something like evite. I've looked everywhere but don't see how to do this. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to dynamically generate an email message for each recipient.
You would alter the Yes/No/Maybe URLs for each recipient so it sends their information to a web page (php/aspx/whatever) that then adds their selection to your database.

So you would loop through your list of recipients, generate the email with a variable altering the url of your Yes/No/Maybe links to something like `http://yoursite.com/rsvp.php?user=<TheUsersName>&selection=<YesNoOrMaybe>`.

Then just have that `rsvp.php` page set up to pull the GET variables you passed with the link and add them to your database.